# Unable to checkout with a downloadable product

Tags: checkout, downloadable

Magento CE 1.8.0.0

I have a single downloadable product (i.e. an ebook). We have guest checkout disabled for downloadable products to prevent sharing. I attempt to checkout with a downloadable product and I can't proceed past step 2 (shipping information) UNLESS I have a physical, simple product in the cart. I monitor console logs and the /var/log directory. ZERO errors.

I monitored the process with Firebug and the last step I'm able to get to is **POST https://www.website.com/checkout/onepage/saveBilling** which has a 200 OK response. It looks like it is trying to skip right over the shipping rate information (which it should) and go directly to the credit card/payment step. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed a fresh CE 1.8.0.0 and created a downloadable product. There were no issues during checkout. There is no step *Shipping Information* in onepage checkout due to the cart containing only virtual (downloadable) products.

In addition to the *response body* of the `saveBilling` response and the *Firebug Console output*, check out

- `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping::isShow()`
- `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::saveBillingAction()`

in order to nail things down.